# How to access to a folder within my app using java in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio, and been working on a little project, but I'm stuck on a function.
Inside my app, I created an "assets" folder, which has another folder inside containing images(.png). Also, I can't use the drawable folder as this folder needs to only contain these images.
I want to use a cycle to get these images and create some objects with them, but I just can't find how to get to this folder within my java code.
Does anyone know how can I do this? or where can I read more in detail about this? It's been a couple of days and I still cant figure it out nor find a site explaining this(that's for sure on me for not knowing the proper terms most likely)-

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.